# Angular ngResource with AppEngine Cursor

Tags: google-app-engine, angularjs

I'm using Google AppEngine as backend and AngularJS as front end for web application I'm making. I'm presenting data in pages to the user.
AppEngine has the ability to select data and return 3 pieces of information: the items selected, indication if there are more items and cursor for the next page.
I need to return all 3 pieces to the client app so it can present the fetched items and allow the user to go to the next page.

I also would like to use ngResource to interact with the server.
The problem is that ngResource expect the list of items to be a list and here it is an object with the 3 pieces.

Is there a way to modify ngResource a bit so that after fetching the data it will use the items to build the array of items?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, `ngResource` can deal with arrays as well as single item or json object. The standard `get` operation returns a object whereas `query` returns array. Bottom line as long it is a valid json data `ngResource` would work.

You can always call `get` on the resource, get the data into a json object and then it can have sub-properties which can be of array type.

You can share your specific structure and the community can help you with understand how to access it using `ngResource`